# Renaming multiple columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5

I have a large dataframe as:

```
z1.ix[1:2]
                  index  LocalTime   Temp   TempDiff   TempNormal   DewPoint  
1  5/16/2018 1:00:00 AM      66.92  -3.89      55.22        66.92        NaN   
2  5/16/2018 2:00:00 AM      66.92  -3.31      53.47        66.02        NaN
```

Above was generated using `pandas.read_csv`

How do I rename the columns so that it appears as following:

```
z1.ix[1:2]
                 LocalTime   Temp   TempDiff   TempNormal   DewPoint  
1  5/16/2018 1:00:00 AM      66.92  -3.89      55.22        66.92            
2  5/16/2018 2:00:00 AM      66.92  -3.31      53.47        66.02
```

Where the column name was shifted left by one place and the last column was dropped.

```
df.rename(columns={'oldCol':'newCol'})
```

is a tedious method to rename the columns as the number of columns for z1 is about 300.

Edit:
My csv file has:

```
NA-KBWI      Hourly Forecast Made May 16 2018 1510 UTC                  
LocalTime    Temp    TempDiff    TempNormal  DewPoint    Cloud Cover     FeelsLikeTemp
5/16/2018 0:00  68  -3.38   57.5    66.92   100 68
5/16/2018 1:00  66.92   -3.89   55.22   66.92   100 66.92
5/16/2018 2:00  66.92   -3.31   53.47   66.02   100 66.92
5/16/2018 3:00  66.92   -2.37   52.88   66.02   100 66.92
```

I am using the following code:

```
pandas.read_csv('myCSV.csv', skiprows=[0])
```

Comment: I suspect you are not reading your CSV properly. Can I see 5-10 rows of your CSV file along with the code that you use to read it? Nipping this problem in the bud is better than solving the XY problem and letting the Y propagate to production code.

Comment: Quick! Before you get more answers that don't actually answer your question...

Comment: I added the file structure but might have been slow as there are plenty of answers already :(

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this is really helpful, but I have one last question for you. Is this a TSV file?

Comment: It could be a TSV file as it is generated by url.

Comment: If it is a CSV, add these parameters: `sep=r'\s{2,}', engine='python', usecols=['LocalTime' ,'Temp' , 'TempDiff','TempNormal', 'DewPoint']` and it works for me. If it is a TSV, omit the `sep` and `engine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df.columns = df.columns[1:].tolist() + ['DropMe']

df.drop('DropMe', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
                   Temp  TempDiff  TempNormal  DewPoint
1  5/16/2018 1:00:00 AM     66.92       -3.89     55.22
2  5/16/2018 2:00:00 AM     66.92       -3.31     53.47
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
df.drop('DewPoint', axis=1)
  .rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns[:-1],df.columns[1:])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below code:

```
new_col = list(pd.Series(list(df.columns)).shift(-1).dropna())
df = df.drop(list(df.columns)[-1], axis=1)
df.columns = new_col
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier is to use the flag `index_col = False` in your [read_csv command](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and you should avoid this problem from the start.

Otherwise you can do something like:

```
old_cols = df.columns.values
#delete the right-most row, which for you is NaN
del df[old_cols[-1]]
new_cols = old_cols[1:]
df.columns = new_cols
```

Answer (score 1):

from what i gather, you are attempting to shift all the column names down.

```
rename_dict = {}
for i in range(len(z1.keys()) - 1):
    rename_dict[z1.keys()[i]] = z1.keys()[i+1]

z1.index.names = [z1.keys()[0]]
z1 = z1.drop(df.keys()[-1], axis=1)
print(rename_dict)
z1.rename(columns=rename_dict)
```

this should do the trick

Comment: This is more complicated and unnecessary than it needs to be, even for the XY problem.

Comment: ya agreed. I generally go for pretty quick fixes for problems like this